# laravel pagination redirecting to index page

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

i have this json like so

```
{#232 ▼
  +"current_page": 1
  +"data": array:2 [▼
    0 => {#230 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"test_col": "Test one"
    }
    1 => {#237 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"test_col": "Test three"
    }
  ]
  +"first_page_url": "http://api/api/test?page=1"
  +"from": 1
  +"last_page": 8
  +"last_page_url": "http://api/api/test?page=8"
  +"next_page_url": "http://api/api/test?page=2"
  +"path": "http://api/api/test"
  +"per_page": 2
  +"prev_page_url": null
  +"to": 2
  +"total": 15
}
```

and in order to get pagination i am doing these piece of code

```
$response =  $response->getBody()->getContents();
$outputs = (json_decode($response));
 $outputs = (json_decode($response));
        $pagination = new LengthAwarePaginator($outputs->data, $outputs->total, $outputs->per_page, $outputs->current_page);
 return view('test.index')->with('outputs',$outputs)->with('pagination',$pagination);
```

now when i come to the front end i can see these
[image]

but when i click on page 2 i am redirected to my index page and when i do
`dd($pagination->links());`
i see this result

```
<ul class="pagination" role="navigation">
    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="&laquo; Previous">
        <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
    </li>

    <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">1</span></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/?page=3">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/?page=4">4</a></li>


    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="/?page=2" rel="next" aria-label="Next &raquo;">&rsaquo;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please ask the question clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with a default [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) system.

Get the data with your controller, like

```php
$perPage = 10;
$data = MyModel::paginate($perPage);
return view('test.index', compact('data'));
```

Then display it in your blade view:

```php
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($data $d)
        {{-- Display the data here --}}   
    @endforeach
</div>
```

The pagination links will automatically be added with

```php
{{ $data-links() }}
```